# VSFTPD: default to local user subdirectory

Tags: vsftpd

The goal: when a local user logs in to ftp, the user is directed to /home/{username}/htdocs.  The expectation is that FileZilla or equivalent will show / and the contents of /home/{username}/htdocs below  Like this:

```
/-
  -file1
  -file2
  |-dir1
  |-dir2
```

The closest I can get is to see / as /home/{username} and then its contents below.

```
/-
  |-htdocs
    |-file1
    |-file2
    |-dir1
    |-dir2
```

I have tried multiple variations on the configurations suggested by all the postings on vsftpd but none seem to get me where I want to go.  Either one can't get there from here or I'm missing something.

I've pared vsftpd.conf to a minimum:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
#chroot_local_user=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftp/users
```

With /etc/vsftp/users containing a file named {username} containing

```
local_root=/home/{username}/htdocs
```

This doesn't get me where I want to go.

So, what am I missing?

[Note: this is in anticipation of no result to my question [about proftpd earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192917/defaultroot-in-proftpd-virtual-host-not-going-to-subdirectory)]

Thanks.

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to install an earlier version of vsftpd!

I had originally just done an install of vsftpd and got versison 2.3.5.  When I got the OOPS message about a writable root I made the user's home directory not writable, etc., ending up with the situation described above.  Further research had me read more closely the commentary on solving the OOPS problem.  One correspondent pointed out that the previous version of vsftpd did not have the constraint on writable roots.  So I dug into the history files to find version 2.3.2.  That version gives me the results I was looking for.

btw, I did try installing version 3.0.2 of vsftpd on my 32-bit virtual machine installation and got an error related to not finding 'crypt'.  Since I was already in way over my head I did not try to resolve that error.  Going backwards, in this case, was better than trying to go forwards.

g