# Restrict user (connecting via vsftpd) to a subdirectory inside another user's home directory

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, shared-folders, vsftpd

I have a problem and I am not sure how to approach it. Some research has let me to different results, like [configuring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193325/vsftpd-default-to-local-user-subdirectory) `vsftpd`, [using](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bindfs-SharedDirectoryLocalUsers) `bindfs` or suggesting to move everything to another shared location, but I am not sure wich is actually the best practise in this example and would like to do it correctly and well.

I serve a website from the home directory of one user, called `user1`. I want to give another user `user2` access via an ftp connection (using `vsftpd`) **only** to the directory of that webserver. I would want that `user2` automatically connects to this folder and is restricted to it and its subdirectories.

My folder structure:

```
/home
  /user1
    /folder1
    /folder2
    /folder-webserver
       /subdirectories
       files
```

Which approach is actually the best practise to do this? Mount the folder in `user2`'s home directory? Or is there a way to configure `vsftpd` to do this? Or create a user group? Or move everything to a shared location?

Thanks for the help, it's appreciated!

Comment: "best" is subjective. You start with a misconception: you -never- use /home for FTP. Never. /home is for local users. When you use SFTP you use a specific directory from / (for instance /sftp/ and best practice would be on  a partition ) You can then create GROUPS and add users to them so they can share directories. You do NOT alter permissions in /home for this.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your remark. Would [this guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/544850/create-new-vsftpd-user-and-lock-to-specify-home-login-directory) be an appropriate solution to what you are talking about?